# Red Hat versus Ubuntu comparison

Tags: ubuntu, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am being asked to use RHEL Red Hat instead of Ubuntu.

Are the basic commands the same?

I know the licensing is different, but are the package mangers/repositories the same?  That is will `sudo apt-get`   still be used?

I have been using Ubuntu for 4 years and have never used Red Hat, so any information will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer - there are differences, including [package management](https://www.wikivs.com/wiki/DEB_vs_RPM?):

> .deb and .rpm files are competing installation package formats for Linux (and other Unix-like) operating systems.
>
> Debs are primarily used for Debian, and derivative distributions (such as Ubuntu)
>
> RPMs are primarily used with Red Hat, Fedora, Suse and derivative distributions (such as Mageia)

Best thing you can do is create a Virtual Machine, install Red Hat, and have a good play. Google will be your friend on this journey ;-)